# How to fix a key that sends a modifier+key

Tags: keyboard, shortcut-keys, keyboard-layout

My laptop has a dedicated lock key, which sends a Super_L+L messing with unity and making it rather useless.

I have no idea how to fix this as I get 2 keycodes with `showkeys` and `acpi_listen` gives no output. Any ideas?

Comment: I've set up Win+L to run the Scale compiz plugin, so the key is useful now. But then, I don't use Unity :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The key code conversion is likely happening within the ACPI BIOS routines, making the key press indistinguishable from a <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd> key sequence.

There is a similar issue with some laptops that generate a <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd> key sequence when you press their dedicated video output switch key, and there isn't much you can do about it.

Depending on how common this lock screen key stroke becomes, Unity may just have to adapt.

Comment: The OP probably got an HP laptop like I do. If yes, then it is indeed controlled by the BIOS and can't be changed.